# How to get pyautogui's click/moveTo working on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui, ios-ui-automation

** Python pyautogui's click and moveTo functions not working ! **

I am running these codes from VSCode.

```py
Import pyautogui
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
print(pyautogui.position())
sleep(1)
pyautogui.moveTo(0,0,2) # moves mouse to (0,0) over 2 seconds
pyautogui.click(0, 0)
sleep(1)
print(pyautogui.position())
```

```py
Output:
Point(x=1084, y=167)
Point(x=1084, y=167)
```

Did not touch the mouse while the program is running.

The position of the mouse cursor was printed out correctly, but
the mouse cursor do not move to the new location (0,0) but stays where it was.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Python 3.8.8 installed with pyobjc and pyobjc-core.
OS : macOS Big Sur
VSCode 1.58

Comment: The movement works for me (on Windows), though I do get the message `pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.`, which is possibly something you will need to look in to.

Comment: The movement works for me, after restart the SVCode, and I get the same error message as you got. However, the message disappears after changing the coordinates from 0,0 to 1,1. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a separate library called [`pynput`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/). You can install it with `pip3 install pynput`. I was facing the same issue the other day and I used `pynput` to fix it. Their documentation is pretty good as well.